# Airplaying: consumption of mobile data?

Tags: ios, airplay, cellular-data

If I create a Personal Hot Spot Wi-Fi (on an iPhone 8 with iOS 12.1.3), connect an Apple TV 4k to that Wi-Fi, will I incure mobile data usage if I airplay to the Apple TV using previously downloaded iTunes movies on the iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

As you are not on a WiFi network, data will be used to transmit the signal.

> If you have no wifi to connect to, then you will using cellular data which will eat up your data. don't want it to eat data, then get a wifi connection.

([Source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6516278))

As you have the move downloaded the data consumption will be reduced but data will still be used.

Comment: So if the content is already downloaded on the phone, transmitting it via Airplay using Personal Hot Spot will entail minimal data usage (from overhead, not from the movie itself, which is already on the phone)? I just want to confirm.

Comment: @yurnero minimal data will be used if the move is downloaded but some data will still be used for the transition